# How to share files between Windows host and Linux guest in VirtualBox, preserving RW-Flag of files?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a Windows host system, running an Ubuntu Linux guest. I have set up a shared folder, which uses the vboxsf filesystem.

The RW-Flag of Windows files does not map to the Linux guest though. Files are always writable. Is it possible to change that? E.g. does using a SMB share help? Can I configure vboxsf to do the mapping?

Comment: Have you seen this ? Is it different from what you want to achieve ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26740113/virtualbox-shared-folder-permissions

Comment: Yes, this is different. It concerns accessing the vboxsf at all from the guest. I have managed to do that. My problem is that the Windows "Read only" flag of a file does not map to Linux file permissions (e.g. it should map to 0440 or r--r----- instead of 0660 rw-rw----).

Comment: I think SMB is your best option.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I have now followed is using an SMB share.

I have added a second host-only network interface to the guest system. On this interface I have bound the Samba server, which shares the needed folder with the Windows host system. This way I have all the features I need.

Comment: This is a recommended solution. It is also described here. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders